# CUDA NVCC compiler binary variable

Tags: cuda, binary, nvidia, nvcc

I'm trying do to something like this in CUDA:

```
char_sig=code[k][1] & 0b00000010;
```

And the NVCC compiler keeps giving me the error   expected a ";"

The same code works with GCC C compiler. I noticed the problem is with setting the binary value as 0b00000010, is there some other notation that NVCC expects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary constants using the `0b` prefix are a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants), and is not part of standard C99 or C++98/C++03. The open64 and LLVM/clang compilers on which the CUDA toolchain is based don't support this. You will need to convert your constants to octal, hexadecimal, or decimal to use them in CUDA.